Recording Status URI Returns Null
I’m working on a React Native app with real-time audio recording and transmission. I’m using expo-av for recording, but the uri property in the recording status object is returning null. Any insights on why this might be happening or how to resolve it?
`const recordingOptions = {
    android: {
        extension: '.m4a',
        outputFormat: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG_4,
        audioEncoder: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_AAC,
        sampleRate: 44100,
        numberOfChannels: 2,
        bitRate: 128000,
    },
    ios: {
        extension: '.caf',
        audioQuality: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_IOS_AUDIO_QUALITY_HIGH,
        sampleRate: 44100,
        numberOfChannels: 2,
        bitRate: 128000,
        linearPCMBitDepth: 16,
        linearPCMIsBigEndian: false,
        linearPCMIsFloat: false,
    },
};

const startRecording = async () => {
    try {
        if (recording) {
            await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
            setRecording(null);
        }
        await Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(true); // Enable audio
        const newRecording = new Audio.Recording();
        await newRecording.prepareToRecordAsync(recordingOptions);
        await newRecording.startAsync();
        setRecording(newRecording);

        newRecording.setOnRecordingStatusUpdate((status) => {
            if (status.isRecording) {
                console.log('Recording audio data:', status.uri);
                socket.emit('audioData', status.uri);
            }
        });`your text`
    } catch (error) {
   console.error('Failed to start recording:', error);
   }
};`

I’ve tried setting the file path using FileSystem.documentDirectory, but the issue persists
